# How to apply global custom style to android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have my `AppTheme` defined in `style.xml` where I apply a custom style globally for all my app's `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button` etc.

Now I'd like to do the same for `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` but how?

It does not extend `EditText` so that style is ignored.

Here's what I've got:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- Globally override default widget styles with custom -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/App.TextView</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/App.Button.Primary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="App.TextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize_normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="App.EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize_xxxlarge</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_hint</item>
    </style>

    <style name="App.Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="App.Button.Primary">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/button_primary_height</item>
        <item name="android:width">@dimen/button_primary_width</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/padding_normal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/padding_normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_primary_text</item>
    </style>

    ...
```

Comment: It actually extends AppCompatEditText which extends EditText. However you are right, styles are not extended.

Comment: Did you find out @Stephan ?

Comment: @thushcapone No; the question still stands. I haven't had the opportunity to look into it since, but a solution is still welcome as I still have it on my TODO.

Answer (score 6):

With the Material theme you can use the **`textInputStyle`** to style the **`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`** component.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
   ....
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle</item>
</style>

<style name=MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
     ....
</style>
```

If you would like to customize the **`TextInputEditText`** just add:

```
<style name=MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
     ....
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">
      @style/MyThemeOverlayTextInputEditTextFilledBox</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeOverlayTextInputEditTextFilledBox">
   <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText</item>
</style>
```

For example:

```
  <style name="MyTextInputEditText" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">myTextAppearance</item>
    ...
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new MDC components allow a lot of flexibility here but it is still quite strange. I wanted a custom font for all TextInputEditTexts, and the filled (default) style. The only way it would work for me is by specifying the font on the TextInputEditText using the global style attribute:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/MyTextField.Outlined</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextFont</item>
</style>

<style name="MyEditTextFont" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTextField" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"/>
<style name="MyTextField.Outlined" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"/>
```

If for example you don't specify the `editTextStyle`, then the `textInputStyle` does work but has crazy missing padding. Anyway I recommend using both of these fields and styling them  both as necessary.

Comment: Don't change the editTextStyle in the app theme. It works globally. Just use materialThemeOverlay attribute in the TextInputLayout style to override the TextInputEditText style only for these components.