# Global style for new com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

Is it possible to style the new **`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`** component without setting it for each component extra?

**For example:**

For the new `TextInputLayout` I can set the style globally in the following way:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
                                .
                                .
                                .
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle</item>
</style>
```

I expect for the **TextInputEditText** a similar way for example:

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditTextStyle</item>
```

but it's not working.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355914/how-to-apply-global-custom-style-to-android-support-design-widget-textinputeditt) is a similar post but only for the old design support components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `TextInputLayout` overrides the `editTextStyle` attribute using the `materialThemeOverlay` attribute.

For example the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` has this default style:

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">
       @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox
    </item>
    ....
</style>
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox</item>
</style>
```

To globally define you have to define a style for the `TextInputLayout` extending one of the [material themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#material-styles).
Then you have to use the new **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute. It allows you to override app theme attributes and you can change the `editTextStyle` attribute.

Something like:

```
  <style name="MyCustomOutlined" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayOutlined</item>    
  </style>
```

In this way you can change the `editTextStyle` (app theme attribute) only for this component style.

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlayOutlined">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText_outlinedBox</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextInputEditText_outlinedBox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    ....
  </style>
```

Finally you can assign the `MyCustomOutlined` to a **specific** `TextInputLayout` in the layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/MyCustomOutlined"
        .../>
```

or assign **globally** in your app theme using:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
   ....
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/MyCustomOutlined</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @StayCool I updated the answer trying to explain why you can't use the `editTextStyle` in app theme. You can define the style globally using the `textInputStyle`.

Comment: Now, when I've found solution, I see taht your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

According to this comment, editTextStyle is the correct attribute to set.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/6c70169e8d4ae77429a9c57785e443b2a18b4aa3/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/attrs.xml#L85

See example usage in these styles:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/6c70169e8d4ae77429a9c57785e443b2a18b4aa3/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/styles.xml#L141

Updated:
Please Set @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText inside your custom TextInputLayoutStyle.

Comment: Could you please try setting materialThemeOverlay inside  MyTextInputLayoutStyle?

Comment: Setting `<item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText</item>` inside my custom TextInputLayoutStyle worked for me. Thanks! Update your answer then I will approve it.